# Get post transition offset of div before transition has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that with rows of boxes on. When a box is clicked it expands height and width which sometimes pushes it down a row if its the last one. There is a .4s transition the box.

I want to scroll to its new location while the transition is happening. Easy to do after by just using setTimeout until the transition is done.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        var divHeight = box.offset().top - 40;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: divHeight
        }, 400);
    }, 400);
```

Is there a way to get the new position of the box before the transition is complete?

**Complete code**

```
$('.expand-button').click(function() {
    var boxContent = $(this).parent();
    var box = boxContent.parent();

    $('.box').removeClass('selected');
    $('.box-content').removeClass('selected');      
    box.addClass('selected');       
    boxContent.addClass('selected');
    $container.isotope();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var divHeight = box.offset().top - 40;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: divHeight
        }, 400);
    }, 400);

});
```

Comment: not pretty but you could add a complete callback to animation and add a fast animation to adjust if needed. Might make it look a bit like an easing animation that way

Comment: Could you expand on that? I'm not sure what you mean. Which animation would the callback be added to?

Comment: callback of animation shown, see docs. Check position again and run another animation if it's not correct